# Installed Package on JupyterHub, now disk quota is exceeded and can’t remove it

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pytorch, jupyterhub

I’m using Jupyter Hub with Python at my university, and I accidentally installed packages torch and torchvision onto the Jupyter hub. Now the disk quota is exceeded (Errno 122) and when I used ‘pip uninstall torch’, it says torch is not found. It’s also not on the list of modules, so I’m assuming it didn’t fully install because it ran out of disk, but now I need to get rid of the rest of the files so that my Jupyter Hub can run smoothly again. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

I’ve tried uninstalling torch and torchvision in a couple different ways to no avail, I assume I need to dig through the terminal to find the partial files.

Comment: Are you sure that `(Errno 122)` is actually being caused by torch?

Comment: @Jamie_D I’m not sure, but when I pip list, torch and torchvision do not show, and ‘pip uninstall torch’ says that torch is not found

Comment: go to the folder when packages are installed and delete it from there. Having said that, it is exceedingly rare for a python package to use all the disk space...